# In Swift, what is the difference between the two different usages of self?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift

In this Swift Xcode 6.0.1 example for a table cell, .self is used as a suffix (don't remember seeing self used like that before), and a prefix self. (which of course is everywhere), trying to understand what that really means.

```
// Register the UITableViewCell class with the tableView

self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: self.cellIdentifier)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your first usage of self as a prefix is a reference to the instance of the class that contains the method that is currently being invoked. In the second usage, self is referring to a type as a value, in this case `UITableViewCell.self` refers to the `UITableViewCell` type

Comment: Ok, i'll make this as answered, but still wondering if I see UITableViewCell by itself, how could the compiler not know it's referring to a UITableViewCell? What other type could it ever be referring to?

Answer (score 3):

`self` is a method that returns the receiver of the message. In this case, it returns the `Class` object for `UITableViewCell`.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's because everywhere else the type is used to type some variable. But `SomeType.self` says to use this type *as the value*. I don't think a type can stand on it's own, unless you call `.self`.

Try the following in a playground.

```
class Foo {}
Foo // ^ Compiler error: expected member name or constructor call after type name
```

But with `.self`

```
class Foo {}
Foo.self // console reports: (Metatype)
```

Comment: Thanks, I wish I could mark multiple answers as solved. Everyone here helped equally in understanding. Ok, more Swift!

Comment: A type can stand on it's own sometimes, e.g. if it is the only argument to a function call.